# How to pass properties to a variable function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function

How to pass properties to a variable function? variable() works but when I try to pass a property i get *"Uncaught TypeError: variable is not a function"*

```js
function firstFunc(a) {
  return `${a}`;
}

let variable = firstFunc();
document.write(variable(1));
```

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to achieve here. `newFunc` is undefined.

Comment: These are not "properties", they are "parameters" or "arguments". There is no such thing as a "variable function", but a variable may **hold** a function. Also, can you please fix your post to use consistent names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You wrote `let variable = firstFunc()`, so variable is the **result** of the execution of `firstFunc()`.

You want instead that `variable` is a reference to the function (like an alias), so you need to do not put the brackets

```js
function firstFunc(a) {
  return `${a}`;
}

let variable = firstFunc;
document.write(variable(1));
```

Answer (score 3):

Two mistakes:

- You confused `firstFunc` and `newFunc`
- To assign a reference to the function to a variable, dont call it `firstFunc()`, just assign it without parenthesis `()`

This works fine in browsers that support the ES6 features you are using:

```js
function firstFunc(a) {
  return `${a}`;
}

let variable = firstFunc;
document.write(variable(1));
```