# What is this sort of String.Format called?

Tags: javascript

This looks like some sort of [`string.Format`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx) in JavaScript.

```js
var some_var = "Alice",
    other_var = "Bob";
var test = `${"Hello " + some_var + ". How is " + other_var + "?"}`;
console.log(test);
```

What is it called? Browser compatibility?

Doubt from this question: [How to pass properties to a variable function in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38252080/17447)

Comment: it's a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). but a bit mixed up.

Comment: [Possible duplicate of `What is the usage of the backtick symbol (`) in JavaScript?`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27678299/247893)

Comment: Use it like this: ` `Hello ${some_var}. How is ${other_var}?`` `;

Comment: @h2ooooooo: I wasnt sure whats the name of that. hence cannot google. also called *grave accent* right?

Comment: @webdeb: Thanks. Thats much simpler.

Comment: @NinaScholz: I tried using it the .NET way. Thats why I got it mixed up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are called ["Template Literals"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

They're part of the [ECMAScript 2015 Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-template-literal-lexical-components).

Answer (score 2):

It's a template literal: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

It's an ES6 feature that's now starting to get support in several js engines.